# Adding localhost entry to Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file with port number

Tags: windows-7, dns, ip-address, localhost, hosts-file

I have set up a local site under IIS 7.5 under port 900. to access it I should type `localhost:900` in the address bar.
I'm a little bit familiar with the System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file and I know I can define my custom name with IP adderss there. For example I can add: `127.0.0.1 MyLocalSite` and whenever I type in `http://MyLocalSite` in the browser, The DNS resolves its IP as 127.0.0.1.
Is there anyway that I can specify port number in that file as well? (e.g. `127.0.0.1:900 MySecondSite` and the DNS resolves it correctly) I tried `127.0.0.1:900` and `127.0.0.1::900` with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kamyar,
Sadly, the hosts file only associates a name to an IP address. Adding a port would make the syntax invalid.

Check out [Windows HOSTS file](http://www.howtonetworking.com/whatis/hosts.htm)

Comment: Tanks Jeff. Too bad.